# Controls in FooterTemplate in Datalist are not enabling disabling

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In Page I have Datalist under that I have one more Datalist i.e. I have inner Datalist.

In inner Datalist I have Footer template as shown below.(Any how I am reduced the code and displaying In case You need more detail please tell)

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
<asp:DataList ID="dtaddedOrderItem" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="dtaddedCartItem_ItemDataBound"  OnItemCommand="dtaddedCartItem_ItemCommand">

<ItemTemplate>
<asp:DataList ID="dtaddedsubserviceitem" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="dtaddedsubserviceitem_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="dtaddedsubserviceitem_ItemCommand">
<FooterTemplate>                                                                                                          
<div id="footeraddserviceshide" runat="server">                                                                                                        
<tr>
<td>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddmainservices" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddmainservices_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdfooterjeweleryid" runat="server" Value="" />
</td>
<td>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddsubservices" runat="server" Visible="false" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddsubservices_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddsizing" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:DropDownList>
 </td>
 <td>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtdescription" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
 <td style="padding: 10px;">
  <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkaddservices" CommandArgument="" runat="server">Add</asp:LinkButton>
 </td>
 </tr>
  </div>
  </FooterTemplate>
 </asp:DataList>
</ItemTemplate>                                                                        
</asp:DataList>
 </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

ON ddmainservices_SelectedIndexChange I have return code as

```
        DropDownList ddmainservices = ((DropDownList)(sender));
        if (ddmainservices.SelectedValue != "0")
        {
            DataListItem dtinner = ((DataListItem)(ddmainservices.NamingContainer));
             TextBox txtdescription = (TextBox)dtinner.FindControl("txtdescription");
            DropDownList ddsubservices = (DropDownList)dtinner.FindControl("ddsubservices");
            DropDownList ddsize = (DropDownList)dtinner.FindControl("ddsizing");              
            ddsubservices.Visible = false;
            ddsize.Visible = false;
            txtdescription.Visible = false;

            if (ddmainservices.SelectedValue == "1")
            {
                ddsubservices.Visible = true;                   
            }
            else if (ddmainservices.SelectedValue == "2")
            {
                txtdescription.Visible = true;
            }
            else if (ddmainservices.SelectedValue == "3")
            {
                ddsize.Visible = true;
            }
     }
```

On change of main drop down I am getting different selected value as 1,2,3 and on debug they fall well in if conditions but any how the visibility is not managed.
Initial the both dropdown and one text box remains hide but when my selected value select as 1 for the first time ddsubservices get visible but then after ddsubservices never get hides.

Comment: These in an UpdatePanel?

Comment: yes I have placed update panel

Comment: I think that's your problem. Try invoking the Update method at the end... you could also alter the markup to have it do the update execution automatically, but see if it works first

Comment: you mean I have to set UpdateMode="Always" for update panel Or you mean to say that I need to remove the update panel

Comment: @GrantThomas on removing updatepanel it is working fine as it should be but I donot want page to get refresed. How should I manage the code

Comment: `UpdatePanel1.Update();`

Comment: You could use `Always`, but you might not always want it to update. If it's conditional and not updating automatically, then you will need to add `<UpdateTrigger>` entries

Comment: @GrantThomas I have already used using UpdatePanel1.Update(); but it is not working in my case